# get all element and value of html in android

Tags: android, html, regex, html-parsing, jsoup

i have some html like this one:

```
<p>text1 &nbsp;</p>
<p><img src="http://theSite.com/apple.png" alt="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed" /></p>
<p><img src="http://theSite.com/sony.gif" alt="cool" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Second Text&nbsp;</p>
<p><img src="http://theSite.com/img.jpg" alt="2" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">TextAgain&nbsp;</p>
```

i need to get element name and some properties of that in a list or array. 
just name of tag (like p) and text of between tag and for img tag  src property.

like this:

```
 String[] elements = {
        "p",
        "p",
        "img",
        "p",
        "img"
    }

String[] values = {
    "text1 &nbsp;",
    "<img src=...",
    "http://thesite.com/apple.png",
    "<img src=...",
    "http://thesite.com/sony.gif"
}
```

is there any library like Jsoup or any method to doing that?

Comment: have you looked into CSS selectors provided by Jsoup? http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow35087945;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

/**
 * Stackoverflow question 35087945
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<p>text1 &nbsp;</p><p><img src=\"http://theSite.com/apple.png\" alt=\"apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed\" /></p><p><img src=\"http://theSite.com/sony.gif\" alt=\"cool\" /></p><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Second Text&nbsp;</p><p><img src=\"http://theSite.com/img.jpg\" alt=\"2\" /></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p style=\"text-align: left;\">TextAgain&nbsp;</p>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = document.select("body *");
        List<String> tagNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element element : elements) {
            String tagName = element.tagName();
            tagNames.add(tagName);
            if ("img".equals(tagName)) {
                values.add(element.attr("src"));
            } else {
                values.add(element.html());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tagNames);
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
[p, p, img, p, img, p, p, img, p, p]
[text1 &nbsp;, <img src="http://theSite.com/apple.png" alt="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed">, http://theSite.com/apple.png, <img src="http://theSite.com/sony.gif" alt="cool">, http://theSite.com/sony.gif, Second Text&nbsp;, <img src="http://theSite.com/img.jpg" alt="2">, http://theSite.com/img.jpg, &nbsp;, TextAgain&nbsp;]
```